A BigQuery Python notebook runs fine manually but fails when scheduled
Problem
I've written a Python notebook in BigQuery, that I've run many times manually without errors, but I've tried for days to run it on a schedule and each run gets a Failed status with this nondescript error:

Error encountered during cell execution.

As Vertex AI also shows all my Python notebooks, but doesn't share the same schedules, I tried creating a new schedule in Vertex for the same notebook and using the Vertex AI's default service account with all the same roles, but there the schedule also fails on every run and gets a similar error:

Error code 3: Error encountered during cell execution.

I checked the Logs Explorer of many of the scheduled run jobs, but all of them had no errors in them, as if everything executed successfully.
Excluded causes
Differences between current and deployed version
The manual runs were made on deployed version of the notebook.
Exceeding some BigQuery quota
I've checked the Quotas & System Limits page and no quotas are exceeded.
Service agent lacking permissions
When a scheduled run fails due to lack of permissions, it gives an error that references a missing permission. No such errors. Also, when creating a schedule for a notebook, a check is made upon selecting a service agent to see if it lacks any permissions and errors would have been raised there too.

While writing this question I decided to make a new notebook and start copying code blocks from the failing notebook to see if running it on a schedule would fail while empty or after adding a specific code block. The culprit turned out to be a python comment before the BigQuery magic code. So for example:
This codeblock will run manually but will fail on a scheduled run giving the nondescript error:
# python comment
%%bigquery testDataFrame --project ProjectName
SELECT * FROM `MyDataset.MyTable`;

While this codeblock will succeed both manually and on a scheduled run:
%%bigquery testDataFrame --project ProjectName
SELECT * FROM `MyDataset.MyTable`;


I had the same issue: Failure due to "Error encountered during cell execution.", on my scheduled python notebook in BigQuery. Although manual execution of the cells works just fine.
Turns out that eliminating all the python comments from
%%bigquery harris_articles --project roundkick-430708
SELECT publication_date, title
FROM roundkick-430708.GDELT.harris_2
will make the schedule run properly.

This appears to be the same answer that's already been given. Please consider deleting your answer, or modify it to be more useful.
